# Dimension and length

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, noetherian, finitely-generated, krull-dimension

I was trying to prove the following:

Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring and let $M$ be a finitely generated $R$-module. Then $M$ has finite length if and only if $\mathrm{dim}(M)=0$.

I was able to prove only one direction:

if $M$ is finitely generated, we have the following ascending chain

$0 = M_0 \subset M_1 \subset \dots \subset M_r = M$

and $M_i/M_{i-1} \cong A/\mathfrak{p_i}$
for $1 \leq i \leq r$, where each $\mathfrak{p_i}$
is a prime ideal of $R$. By hypothesis
$\mathrm{dim}(R/\mathrm{Ann}_R(M))= 0$ this means that every prime ideal in $R/\mathrm{Ann}_R(M)$ (that is, every prime ideal of $R$ containing $\mathrm{Ann}_R(M)$) is a maximal ideal. Moreover, since $\mathrm{Ann}_R(M) \subseteq p_i$ for all $i$, we conclude that each quotient $M_i/M_{i-1}$ is a simple module, hence $M$ has finite length.

I'm having some trouble proving the other one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $M$ has finite length. Let’s show that there’s a finite product $P$ of maximal ideals such that $PM=0$.

If this is the case, then we have a surjection $R/P \rightarrow R/\mathrm{Ann}(M)$, thus $\dim{M}=0$ (because the only prime ideals of $R/P$ are maximal).

Indeed, $M$ has finite length, so there is a sequence $0=M_0 \subset M_1 \subset M_2 \ldots \subset M_r=M$ such that $M_i/M_{i-1}$ is simple: it is of the form $R/\mathfrak{m}_i$ for some maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}_i$, and $P=\prod_i{\mathfrak{m}_i}$ fits the bill.

Comment: thank you, but I don't get why $P=\prod \mathfrak{ m}_i$ is such that $PM=0$

Comment: Show by descending induction that $\prod_{j > i}{\mathfrak{m}_j}M \subset M_i$ (as $\mathfrak{m}_jM_j \subset M_{j-1}$).

Comment: where does the inclusion $\mathfrak{m}_jM_j\subset M_{j-1}$ come from? I was thinking: the quotients $M_j/M_{j-1}\cong R/\mathfrak{m}_j$ where $\mathfrak{m}_j=Ann(\bar{x}_j)$ with $0\neq\bar{x}_j\in M_j/M_{j-1} $ so, for sure $\mathfrak{m}_jx_j \in M_{j-1}$ for eah $x_j\in \bar{x}_j$. but what if $x'_j\not\in\bar{x}_j$?

Comment: Because we’ve taken a maximal decomposition, $\overline{x_j}$ is the whole of $M_j/M_{j-1}$.

Comment: right, I got it now! thank you so much :)